# How to create a new connection at runtime in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, database-connection, laravel-5

I'm trying to develop a kind of "time machine" that will allow the user to "travel" in time the databases of each day and eventually merge them and so on...

I'm building this in Laravel 5.2, in fact I think that at the beginning, this will be a Laravel package. The question is:

How can I create a new connection configuration at runtime? Can I access that array and add a new config and hope that Laravel will connect to it later when I will use it? If yes, how can I push this into the array?

I've googled around for a while but all that I've found was related to the connection switching at runtime.

Thank you all, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You want to change the database to be used on the runtime. right ?

Comment: @jaysingkar that's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new connection configuration at runtime with using the middleware. In that particular middleware you need to set new connection or change the datatabase. Can you please specify more about.

Comment: I would like to have a method that I can use from my controller that can be: 
$Tm->cloneDb(time()); where it cares about the dump of the db. What I need is to know if I can firstly dump the data, then create a new db and then switch to the new db... Hope it makes sense...

Comment: As per your requirement you need to follow the following steps
 
`Step 1 - Dump the tables`
 
`Step 2 - Create new database on fly and connect to new  db`    

`Step 3 - Create migration table and then call migrations script
              Using the Artisan::call('migrate',['--path' => "migration path"]);`
                    
`Step 4 - Insert data in newly connected database`

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'll try this out. But I think that it will surely work